# Question from Rudin: Jensen?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, inequality

I came across this question from Rudin's *Real and Complex Analysis*, 3rd Edition (p.75 # 25)

> "Suppose that $\mu$ is a positive measure on $X$ and $f:X\rightarrow (0,\infty)$ satisfies $\int_X f d\mu = 1$.  Prove for every $E \subset X$ with $0 < \mu(E) < \infty$ that $\int_E(\log{f})d\mu \leq \mu(E)\log{\frac{1}{\mu(E)}} $
>
> Also, when $0<p<1$, we have $\int_E{f^p}d\mu \leq \mu(E)^{1-p}$."

My first thought was that since log is a concave function, we can use Jensen's inequality (in the opposite direction), but that is not giving me what I want.  Any suggestions?

Further Addendum : Jensen's inequality only works on a set of measure 1 (or by redefining an interval to get a measure 1 set) so this is clearly not the correct approach.

Comment: Rudin has several analysis texts. Is this from _Real and Complex Analysis_? If so, what edition? My edition gets up to a problem 21 on page 74 and starts a new chapter on page 75.

Comment: This is from Rudin Real and Complex Analysis 3rd edition.  This is from the exercises on the Lp space chapter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First note that since we are only interested in $f$ on $E$, the condition $\int_X f\,d\mu=1$ translates to $\int_E f\,d\mu\le1$.

Let $\bar{f_E}=\int_E f\,d\mu/\mu(E)\le 1/\mu(E)$ denote the average value of $f$ on $E$. We then get
$$
\int_E \ln f\,d\mu
\le\int_E \ln\bar{f_E}\,d\mu
=\mu(E)\ln\bar{f_E}
\le\mu(E)\ln\frac{1}{\mu(E)}.
$$

Replace the logarithm with power $p$, and the second result follows in exactly the same manner.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use Jensen's Inequality, then you must check the measure 1 condition first, as you say.

Here,since $\mu(E)$ may not be 1,you can change the measure $\mu$ to $\frac{1}{\mu(E)}\mu$. That is, you can apply the Jensen's inequality(for concave function) as follows:

$$
\frac{1}{\mu(E)}\int_E\rm{log} \,f\,\rm{d}\mu\le \rm{log}\left(\frac{1}{\mu(E)}\int_E \,f\,\rm{d}\mu\right)\le\rm{log}\frac{1}{\mu(E)}.
$$ 
You can do this similarly by change $\rm{log} f$ to $f^p$.